# Display img receive from API as Stream

Tags: javascript, html

How can I read a stream from the api to display it in the src of an img tag ?

[image: response as stream]

With this response I just want to display it in a `<img src="myStream" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first error was to try to display a `pdf` file in an `<img/>` tag. I used an `<iframe />` instead.

Also I had to use `fetch` to make the request and after use `response.blob()` :

```
const myFunctionToConvertHttpResponseToFileUrl = () => async {
   const response = await fetch('myurl.com')
   const myBlob = response.blob()
   this.fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
}

And After in the html

<iframe :src="fileUrl" type="application/pdf" />
```